# QGIS export to ESRI-JSON

Tags: qgis, geojson

I am trying to export a layer from QGIS (3.22) GeoPackage to GeoJSON format using the Save as function, and I want it to be readable in ESRI applications for interoperability. Nonetheless when I use the the JSON to Feature function in ArcGIS Pro I get the following error:

> 001558: Error parsing .json file

> Description:
> The JSON structure does not conform to ESRI-JSON standard for feature sets.

> Solution: Review the JSON structure in the input file. The JSON must have at least the geometryType, spatialReference, fields, and features (with geometry and attributes) property

I have tested various options in the QGIS export dialog but I don't seem to get it right. Is there a simple way to export to ESRI-JSON standard from QGIS?

Comment: If you want to export to Esri JSON, you don't want to use GeoJSON -- they're different formats.

Comment: And don't believe ESRI That is not a standard

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/json-to-features.htm

> The input file extension determines the format used by the tool for
> proper conversion. For Esri JSON formatted file, use the .json
> extension; for GeoJSON formatted files, use the .geojson extension.

If your GeoJSON file that is saved from QGIS is named as .json, rename it into .geojson and ArcGIS Pro should be happy with it.

**EDIT**

I made a test as follows:

- With QGIS 3.30, export a polygon layer into GeoJSON with "save as" into a file named "jsontest.geojson"
- With ArcGIS Pro 2.4.1, import "jsontest.geojson" file with the "JSON to Features" geoprocessing tool

I had no problems at all.

**EDIT**

I could also import your countriestest3035.geojson file without errors

[image]

Comment: AS far as I can see the export dialog in QGIS only allows to export to GeoJson format, with .geojson extension, which is not parsed correcly in ArcGIS but returns the error as described above

Comment: It works for me. See the edited answer. Could you share your GeoJSON file? Maybe there is something special in it.

Comment: many thanks for your comment, yes here are the the files I am using for testing:  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/pus0rdy4l28n2e0t1ng48/h?dl=0&rlkey=ma3ud7limr057e7dou8vwc4o2



I am using a sample SHP of countries from Eurostat, I've tried exporting in gpkg first and also directly to geojson format from QGIS using the Save as/Export function, both leaving everything else as default or changing manually some parameters (e.g. geometry type and CRS) but I still get the ESRI error message. I have also inspected the geojson file structure and seems fine to me, but I am not an expert

Comment: See the edited answer. I had no problems with your data. I suggest to contact your ESRI dealer and ask for help, you have already paid them. They may tell as usual that they can't do anything because the GeoJSON is not created with any ESRI product, but have a try still. Maybe there is something wrong with your installation. It is obvious that your ArcGIS tries to open the data with a wrong driver, the ESRI-json driver. Maybe it does not have the GeoJSON driver or it is broken.

Comment: wow, good to know it works for you! At least QGIS conversion is done properly. Many thanks  for your feedback, will check with ESRI as suggested.